# txt file not found when importing the crate

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I created a library that in order to work needs to parse a txt file every time you call the main method. The problem is that when importing into another project the txt file can not be found because I'm using env::current_dir(), when I call the method from the library folder current folder is the crate's root, and I can access root/src/my_file.txt. When importing and using the library the root is different and there isn't any my_file.txt.
How can resolve this? [Here is the Crate](https://crates.io/crates/gender_guesser)

Here is how I access the file.

```rust
 fn parse(&mut self, name_to_find: &str) -> () {
        let p = env::current_dir().unwrap();
        println!("{}", p.display());
        let file = File::open(format!("{}/src/nam_dict.txt", p.display())).unwrap();
        let lines = BufReader::new(file).lines();
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust is a compiled language, so one can't assume access to the sourcecode and adjacent files at runtime.

So your options are

- Include it at compile time with the [include_str!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_str.html) macro. This means changes to the file won't be picked up until the library and its dependents are rebuilt
- Locate the file at runtime, e.g. through a specified location (such as somewhere in the config hierarchy in the user's home directory), an environment variable, a commandline option or from the current directory. This way the file can be changed without recompiling the program but the user has to know that he must provide it.

More complicated approaches such as including a default configuration and letting the user override it are also possible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I managed how to do it. I used build scripts where I parsed the txt file inside the build.rs and used returned value in lib.rs very easily.